# Scaling heat map colours for multiple heat maps

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap, rescale

So I have a bunch of matrices that I am trying to plot as a heatmaps. I am using the `heatmap.2()` function in the ggplot2 packaage.

I have been trying for quite some time with it, and I am sure there is a very simple fix, but my issue is this:

How do I keep the colours consistent between heatmaps? For example, to make the values that provide the colours absolute as opposed to relative.

I have tried doing something similar to this question:

[R/ggplot: Reuse color key for multiple heat maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23417545/r-ggplot-reuse-color-key-for-multiple-heat-maps)

But I was unable to figure out the `ggplot` function; I kept receiving an error message stating that there were "no layers in plot".

After reading the comments on the above question, I tried using `scales::rescale()` and `discrete_scale()` but the former does not remove the problem, while the latter did not work.

I am fully aware that I might be doing something very simple wrong, and just being a bit of an idiot, but for the life of me I can't figure out where I am going wrong.

As for the data itself, I am trying to plot 10 matrices/heatmaps, each 10x10 cells (showing change over time) and the values in the cells range from 1.0 to 1.2.

As an example, this is the code I am using (once I have my 10x10 matrix).

```
Matrix1<-matrix(data=(runif(100,1.0,1.2)),nrow=10,ncol=10)
heatmap.2(Matrix1, Colv=NA, Rowv=NA, dendrogram="none",
    trace="none", key=F, cellnote=round(Matrix1,digits=2),
    notecex=1.6, notecol="black",
    labRow=seq(10,100,10), labCol=seq(10,100,10),
    main="Title1", xlab="Xlab1", ylab="Ylab1"
 )
```

So any help with either figuring out how to create the scaled values for the `heatmap.2()` function, or how I can use the `ggplot()` function would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: As far as I know `ggplot2:::heatmap.2` is not in the ggplot2 package.

Comment: @TylerRinker Correct. It's in the **gplots** package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's important to note that `heatmap.2` is not a `ggplot2` function. The `ggplot2` package is not necessarily compatible with all plotting types. If you look at the `?heatmap.2` help page, in the upper left corner it shows you where the function is from. `heatmap.2 {gplots}` means that function comes from the `gplots` package. These are different pacakges so they have different rules how they work.

To get the same colors across different heatmaps, you want to explicitly get the `breaks=` parameter. By default it splits the observed range of the data into equal chunks. But since each data set may have a different min and max, these chunks may have different start and end points. By specifying `breaks`, you can make them all consistent. Since your data ranges from 1 to 1.2, you can set

```
mybreaks <- seq(1.0, 1.2, length.out=7)
```

and then in your call add

```
heatmap.2(Matrix1, Colv=NA, Rowv=NA, dendrogram="none",
    ...
    breaks=mybreaks,
    ...
 )
```

That should make them all match up.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help you. With the following code multiple heatmaps are stored in a list and displayed in a grid later on. This will allow you to control the colours of each heatmap since each heatmap is created separately. So in this case I chose to use green and red for the number range in each chart.

```
data(mtcars)
require(ggplot2)
require(gridExtra)


myplotslist2 <- list()
var = c("mpg", "wt", "drat")
new = cbind(mtcars, "variable")
new = cbind(car = rownames(mtcars), new)
for (i in 1:length(var)){
  t= paste("new[[\"variable\"]] = \"", var[[i]],"\"; a = ggplot(new, aes(variable, car)) + geom_tile(aes(fill = ", var[[i]], "),colour = \"white\") + scale_fill_gradient(low = \"red\", high = \"green\") + theme(axis.title.y=element_blank(), axis.text.y=element_blank(),legend.position=\"none\"); myplotslist2[[i]] = a")
  eval(parse(text=t))
}


grid.arrange(grobs=myplotslist2, ncol=length(var))
```

The result looks like this:
[image: Heatmap]

I hope this helps.

I explain more in my blogpost. https://dwh-businessintelligence.blogspot.nl/2016/05/pca-3d-and-k-means.html